# Unable to open the summary file for INBOX. Perhaps there was an error on disk, or the full path is too long

Tags: thunderbird

Unable to open the summary file for INBOX. Perhaps there was an error on disk, or the full path is too long...pops up every time I try to open Thunderbird email or inbox unless I open it in Windows first.  This just started happening after the last Ubuntu Update I did.  I've been using Ubuntu for many years and this is the first problem I have ever had with Thunderbird.  It's very odd that shutting down Ubuntu [completely], opening Windows, then opening Thunderbird in Windows produces no errors. 
Your presumption that Windows/Ubuntu is not closed is not correct.  The computer is shut down between operating systems.  Unless I open Thunderbird in Windows first, it will not open in Ubuntu.  I can't open it in Ubuntu without the error message.  In addition, when it does open, it is locked up.  This is an Ubuntu problem - not a Windows problem.  There are no simultaneous connections to Thunderbird.

Comment: Provide more explicit detail on your specific situation (open it in Windows?). I presume Windows may be set to shut down quickly. Then, the file system is not properly closed and cannot be accessed by Linux.

Comment: As @vanadium said, just because Windows is "shut down" it does not mean it executes a clean shutdown. "With fast startup enabled, choosing to shut down your PC might look like you're completely shutting things down, but in reality, your PC is entering a mix between a shutdown and hibernation." You should disable fast startup in Windows and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I have never enabled fast startup.  In fact, I have disabled all MS nonsense.  I am not rebooting.  I am shutting down completely.

Comment: День сумо on Mozillazine help site offered a solution that was simple and effective.  Apparently, the Thunderbird update in the Ubuntu update corrupted the .msf file for the Inbox.  Repairing that cost me a couple of insignificant email, but got Thunderbird working in Ubuntu as well as in Windows.  Please feel free to pass this on to the many other people I found in my research of this problem who are experiencing similar problems.